# Can't see family sharing invitation on iPad mini

Tags: ipad, icloud, family-sharing

I created a Family Sharing invitation and sent it to an email address. In a new iPad mini (running iOS 8.1.2) I find the email message and click on the "View Invitation" link.  It immediately takes me to the iCloud settings, but there are no details about the invitation and no indication about how I should proceed. This iPad has not been previously associated with any Apple ID. How can I associate this device with the Apple ID associated with the invitation?

Comment: pretty sure it needs to already have an ID associated to it - otherwise what 'family' could it be invited to? [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) is 'linking IDs' by definition.

Comment: This tablet is for a small kid, so she can't get her own apple id. The instructions I've seen say to use family sharing to get an invitation. Just for fun I also tried to apply the invitation after having created a bogus apple ID and had the tablet set up using that, but the invitation still took me to the no-op iCloud settings.

Comment: same applies - needs an account - [Family Sharing for Kids](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084)

Comment: same problem confirmed on iPhone 5C and iPad Retina, where AppleID was newly created for an adult

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that your device is running the version of iOS that you think that it is under Settings > General

It might help to associate devices with that Apple ID, or at least log in to iTunes with the Apple ID to make sure that everything about the Apple ID works
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074

You can also get to the invitation from Settings > iCloud > Family Sharing

here is info from the start
http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/setup-family-sharing-iphone-ipad-ios-8.html

I was able to resolve all of my issues.